# "I can't help but agree"

Tags: grammaire

This is a tricky one and I'm not sure how well it translates.

For the piece I am writing, I say that 'everyone says I do well in ..... ' . Next, I want to say "and I can't help but agree".

The only transation I got was "je ne peux pas aider mais d'accord", but It looks too literally translated.

Does anyone know how to say this in French? Thank you.

Comment: How did you come up with this translation?  [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/je+ne+peux+m'emp%C3%AAcher+d'%C3%AAtre.html), [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/I%20can't%20help%20but), [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/can't%20help%20doing%20sth) ...

Answer (score 4):

> Je ne peux pas aider mais d'accord

doesn't work at all, it's too literal and not quite correct. I would say:

> Je suis bien forcé d'admettre que c'est vrai.

or

> Je ne peux pas m'empêcher d'être d'accord.

which is maybe closer to the English.

One more:

> Force est de reconnaitre que c'est vrai.